# Sending rest api routes to client

Tags: rest

I'm looking for a better way to structure my rest client/rest api code. Currently, I have my rest api with routes like:

```
get /book
```

The literal string "/book" is defined on the server side, and on the client side, I have to use the same literal string exactly.

What I would like to do is, have a file serverside which has all of my routes in it, and send it to the client as json, which the client uses for routing.

The basic workflow would be:

- Start the server
- When the client connects, make a get request for the routes object
- return an object like this:

  ```
  {
   getBook:"/book",
   createBook:"/book/create"
  }
  ```

that way my client can use the object returned for the routes instead of hard coding them.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: great idea, but someone beat you to it. Look at hateoas

Comment: Yup. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS